# Import error ft2font from matplotlib (python, macosx)

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

I was installing matplotlib to use basemap today when I had to install a lot of stuff to make it work. After installing matplotlib and be able to import it I installed basemap but I can't import basemap because of this error:

> > > from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
> > >
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/**init**.py", line 36, in 
> > >           from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
> > >         File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 22, in 
> > >           import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases
> > >         File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 38, in 
> > >           import matplotlib.widgets as widgets
> > >         File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/widgets.py", line 16, in 
> > >           from lines import Line2D
> > >         File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/lines.py", line 23, in 
> > >           from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
> > >         File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 52, in 
> > >           from matplotlib import ft2font
> > >       ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/ft2font.so, 2): Symbol not found: _FT_Attach_File
> > >         Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/ft2font.so
> > >         Expected in: dynamic lookup

So when I tried to import ft2font in python by:

> > > from matplotlib import ft2font

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/ft2font.so, 2): Symbol not found: _FT_Attach_File
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/ft2font.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

Any idea what to do?
I'm using Mac OSX 10.6 and python 2.7.2 installed by homebrew.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix ImportError in matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120265/how-to-fix-importerror-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same issue. Even after running `make.osx`, it still complained about `_FT_Attach_File` being undefined when I imported `ft2font` from matplotlib. Here's how I tracked down the problem. Hopefully, it will help someone else.

Running `otool -L ft2font.so` yielded:

```
    ft2font.so:
/Users/jbenuck/mpl_build/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 52.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)
```

Note the absence of any mention of libfreetype! How is `ft2font.so` supposed to locate the symbol if it isn't linked against it?

My next step was to capture the commands used during the build:

```
    make -f make.osx PREFIX=/usr/local clean fetch deps mpl_build > output.txt
```

Searching this yielded the command that was used to compile the offending python module. I changed the value of the output file to be one in my local directory and ran it:

> /Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -isysroot / -L/opt/local/lib -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -L/usr/local/lib -syslibroot,/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/src/ft2font.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/src/mplutils.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/CXX/cxx_extensions.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/CXX/cxxsupport.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/CXX/IndirectPythonInterface.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/CXX/cxxextensions.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/X11/lib -lfreetype -lz -lstdc++ -lm -o ft2font.so
>
> ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/local/lib/libfreetype.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)

Bingo! Problem found. I know I have both macports and homebrew installed. Apparently, one of them has a version of `libfreetype` in `/opt/local/lib` that isn't compiled for 64-bit.

I reran the command with `"-L /opt/local/lib"` removed which worked without a warning. Copying the resulting `ft2font.so` into my existing matplotlib installation now allows me to successfully import `ft2font` from matplotlib.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, this was an architecture problem - I had a 64bit version of freetype installed (that matplotlib happily compiled against) but when I ran in a 32bit version of python I got that error. The easy solution is to uninstall everything (freetype, matplotlib), and then install both the 32 and 64bit versions using homebrew and the --universal flag:

```
brew install freetype --universal
```

Note, I also had to do this for libpng as well (`brew install libpng --universal`). Not all homebrew recipes support the universal flag, but it's a huge help for the ones that do. (You can see a formula's options with `brew info <FORMULA>`).

Also, compiling using the make.osx Makefile in conjunction with homebrew was a total failure; in my experience I'd recommend one or the other.

Comment: This worked for me. My problem: I originally installed python **without** the `--universal` option then installed matplotlib. For some unrelated reasons I needed both 32 and 64 bit python installations so I reinstalled with homebrew, this time using the `--universal` option and reinstalled matplotlib. However, some of the dependencies like truetype and png also needed to be updated with the universal option. So in addition I also had to run `brew install libpng --universal`.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I figured it out.

I reinstalled matplotlib from source from github (https://github.com/matplotlib/) and then (instead of ordinary python setup.py install) I ran make.osx described in README.OSX:

```
make -f make.osx PREFIX=/devjunk PYVERSION=2.7 \
  clean fetch deps mpl_install_std
```

And everything works properly now.