# Pycharm: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pycharm, importerror

Then trying to import matplotlib in Python 3.7 using:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

The following error is given.

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:/Users/EDRM/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 2, in <module>
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
File "C:\Users\EDRM\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py"
line 174, in <module> _check_versions()
File "C:\Users\EDRM\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 159, in _check_versions
from . import ft2font
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have installed matlabplot via terminal, same error occurred, uninstalled it via terminal. Installed via settings, same issue. Uninstalled via terminal, and reinstalled, but nothing helped.

in: C:\Users\EDRM\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib I can find the pyplot file. What is the issue and how do I resolve it?

Cheers

Comment: maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503058/import-error-ft2font-from-matplotlib-python-macosx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this was the case however by downgrading matplotlib to version 3.0.3 the above problem was resolved. Type the following in terminal:

```
pip uninstall matplotlib

pip install matplotlib==3.0.3
```

Answer (score -3):

just write `import pandas` and most probably it will solve your problem

[image]

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Comment: And for future posts, please post codes as **TEXT**, not as a picture like this.